# How to split a string into "blocks", where each block is a sub-string of the text, closed around 2 special brackets?

Tags: python

I have a txt file. let's call it myFile.txt
and let's say this file contains this text inside it:

```
~[~some Words~]~ hideMe~[~Another Words~]~don't Show me~{~me too~}~bb[what about me?]
```

I want my output to be an array with the following strings:
`{"some Words", "Another Words"}`

In words, i want to seperate the whole text and leave only the text inside each special-squared-brackets,  `~[~` and `~]~`, and append each block to the output array.
In the example above, notice that the `"what about me?"` string does NOT included in the output. This is because it's not blocked inside a `~[~` and  `~]~` as it should.

My attempt was to use

```
file = open("myFile.txt", 'r')
output = file.split("~[~")
```

but I don't know how to continue from here. There's still so much text to "get rid off".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.findall` we can try:

```py
inp = "~[~some Words~]~ hideMe~[~Another Words~]~don't Show me~{~me too~}~bb[what about me?]"
matches = re.findall(r'~\[~(.*?)~\]~', inp)
print(matches)  # ['some Words', 'Another Words']
```

Comment: ok that may work! But how do i write it more generically? I tried to do the exact thing that you just did, only using variables, but it didn't work:
```inp = "~[~some Words~]~ hideMe~[~Another Words~]~don't Show me~{~me too~}~bb[what about me?]"```
```start = '~[~'```
```end = '~]~'```

```matches = re.findall(rf'{start}(.*?){end}', inp)```
```print(matches)```

Comment: oh i'm sorry about that.. i can't seem to use the ``` properly for some reason

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the square brackets `[` and `]`, which are reserved in Regular Expression to group characters together. For example, expanding from your comment:

```
import re

inp = "~[~some Words~]~ hideMe~[~Another Words here~]~don't Show me~{~me too~}~bb[what about me?]~[~SingleWord~]~don't Show me~[~What_about_me~]~don't Show this:~[~~]~"
start = '~\[~'    # start = re.escape('~[~')    #same
end = '~\]~'      # end = re.escape('~]~')      #same
matches = re.findall(f'{start}([a-zA-Z\s]+){end}', inp)
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['some Words', 'Another Words here', 'SingleWord']
```

Note that `~[~What_about_me~]~` and `~[~~]~` are not picked up, depending on whether you need them.

Comment: It would be better to call `re.escape` on the start and end strings.

Comment: thanks @TimBiegeleisen I'm learning from you!